# Vs2013 MVC5 app SLN load all projects on one machine, none on another

Tags: visual-studio-2013, projects-and-solutions

Iv'e got a MVC5 app. in Vs 2013.

On my primary box, everything loads and works
on my second box none of the projects load successfully.
but all I get for info is that they don't load, no reason why, no error.

I'm assuming this is some missing prerequisite, so in made sure the correct .net version was there (4.5.2), repaired it anyway, and made sure MVC5 was there.

No Joy.

Any idea what other things might be causing this issue?

VS2013 works for other apps, TFS works correctly... but no projects load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out...

If I click on a specific project and tell it to reload manually, it gives me the Error.

It then told me that .Net 4.5.2 wasn't installed, even though I'd run the installer and repaired it.

So I shut down all VS instances and ran the Web Installer (instead of the offline) and it then installed again, (instead of repairing) and it now works.

Why I had to use a different installed I dunno...